# How to get only nodes of root node in xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse an xml file. It is giving all nodes of root but I want only child nodes, don't want the grandchild nodes. How can I get those?
my xml is:

```
<Pdf_Format>
    <SpaceSep>0</SpaceSep>
    <text>           GLOBUS</text>
    <LineSep>2</LineSep>
    <text>***************************************</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
    <text>Maxus Mall 2nd Floor S/11Timba</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
    <text>Near Hyover Bridge Bhayander</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>0</SpaceSep>
    <text>            022-28170870</text>
    <LineSep>2</LineSep>
    <text>=======================================</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <text>=======================================</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <param>ReprintBill</param>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
    <text>Qty</text>
    <SpaceSep>4</SpaceSep>
    <text>Item</text>
    <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
    <SpaceSep>6</SpaceSep>
    <text>Price</text>
    <SpaceSep>5</SpaceSep>
    <text>Total</text>
    <SpaceSep>2</SpaceSep>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
    <text>---</text>
    <SpaceSep>4</SpaceSep>
    <text>----</text>
    <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
    <SpaceSep>6</SpaceSep>
    <text>-----</text>
    <SpaceSep>5</SpaceSep>
    <text>-----</text>
    <SpaceSep>2</SpaceSep>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <product>
        <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
        <param>Qty</param>
        <SpaceSep>3</SpaceSep>
        <param>ItemID</param>
        <SpaceSep>1</SpaceSep>
        <param>PriceSubDisc</param>
        <SpaceSep>1</SpaceSep>
        <param>TotalSubDisc</param>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <param>TN</param>
        <SpaceSep>6</SpaceSep>
        <param>Desc</param>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <SpaceSep>16</SpaceSep>
        <param>ActualPrice</param>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <param>Reason</param>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    </product>
    <LineSep>2</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>11</SpaceSep>
    <text>Sub Total    </text>
    <SpaceSep>5</SpaceSep>
    <param>SubTotal</param>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>11</SpaceSep>
    <text>Tax          </text>
    <SpaceSep>5</SpaceSep>
    <param>Tax</param>
    <LineSep>2</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>11</SpaceSep>
    <text>Final Total  </text>
    <SpaceSep>5</SpaceSep>
    <param>FinalTotal</param>
    <Transactions>
        <LineSep>1</LineSep>
        <SpaceSep>11</SpaceSep>
        <param>Mode</param>
        <SpaceSep>5</SpaceSep>
        <param>Amount</param>
    </Transactions>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>1</SpaceSep>
    <text>Sales Associate:</text>
    <param>CashierName</param>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <text>========================================</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <text>CST TIN:27020000519C W.E.F. 01-04-2006</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <text>VAT TIN:27020000519V W.E.F. 01-04-2006</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <text>No Exchange and No Refunds</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <text>========================================</text>
    <LineSep>1</LineSep>
    <SpaceSep>1</SpaceSep>
    <text>Trx</text>
    <SpaceSep>2</SpaceSep>
    <param>BillId</param>
    <SpaceSep>2</SpaceSep>
    <param>StoreCode</param>
    <SpaceSep>2</SpaceSep>
    <param>Counter</param>
    <SpaceSep>2</SpaceSep>
    <param>BillDate</param>
    <SpaceSep>2</SpaceSep>
    <param>BillTime</param>
    <LineSep>6</LineSep>
</Pdf_Format>
```

and To get the nodes I have written the statement:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(XMLFilePath);
foreach (XElement node in loadedData.Descendants())
```

so in this xml **I dont want** the childnodes of **Product** and **Transactions**
Please help me..

Comment: XPath and XPathSelectElements()

Comment: do you want just to ignore Product and Transactions elements altogether? or just the child Nodes of these?

Comment: Descendants() gives children and grandchildren while Elements() only gives the children.

Comment: I want to ignore the child nodes of Product and Transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

> Returns a collection of the child elements of this element or document, in document order.

Example:

```
foreach (XElement node in loadedData.Elements())
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved myself like this.

```
foreach (XElement node in loadedData.Descendants())
            {
                if ((node.Parent != null && (node.Parent.Name.LocalName == "product")))
                {
                    if ((node.Parent != null && node.Parent.Name.LocalName == "Transactions"))
                    { }
                }

                else
                {
               //some code here
                }
            }
```